# UI update in didEnterRegion?

Tags: ios, objective-c, geofencing

I'm making an app that features the use of geofencing using a CLLocationManager. I've implemented these two methods and they are both getting called appropriately:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    [self updateUI]; // update the UI
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    [self updateUI]; // update the UI
}
```

I'm doing a set of UI updates in a method called updateUI like so:

```
- (void)updateUI
{
    // Update labels, constraints, alphas and similar
}
```

updateUI is called within didEnterRegion and didExitRegion, but that raises a few questions:

- How does that work when the app is in the background?
- Should I detect if the app is open or in the background, then do the UI update in viewWillAppear instead?
- If updating the UI is a bad thing to do in these didEnterRegion and didExitRegion, what exactly are the consequences of doing it?

Thanks!

Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app was not in the foreground when the notification arrived, it won't be foregrounded. Thus there is very little point doing anything to the interface at this point, because, in effect, there is no interface. Just process the notification in some way - i.e. note down what happened - and stop. Your job at this point is to get out of there as fast as possible and let the app go back to sleep. The next time your app comes to the front (becomes active), you'll get a notification of *that*, and *now* you can make the interface match the data.

Comment: Yeah, I'll just create a string or something in NSUserDefaults, then read from that in viewWillAppear and determine if I need to do any UI update then. How can I check if the app is in the foreground or background?

Comment: Really? You can't figure out how to ask the application if it's the background or the foreground? Really?

Comment: yeah, sorry. I figured it out.. Thanks though!

Comment: so, if I change the VC in didEnterRegion when the app was killed, the changes will just be dismissed and forgotten? I recall that showing a UIAlertView in didEnterRegion when the app was killed made the alert display when the app was reopened, why is that?

Comment: @Erik If you're running in the background, I don't think interface changes will be forgotten. But in general there's a kind of MVC violation there, in my view; there's no point updating the interface unless the user is about to _see_ the interface. - It's true that showing an alert is a hacky trick for forcing a background app to the foreground, but in my opinion that's all it is: a trick.

Comment: problem is that I need to do a set of UI updates in didEnter/ExitRegion. Currently I'm checking if the app is in the background or foreground, and then if background, leave a trace telling the app to do when it goes back to the foreground - but viewWillAppear won't be called when reopening the app, so I'm not sure where to handle the trace that didEnterRegion left behind.

Comment: `applicationDidBecomeActive` will be called and the corresponding notification will fire. I said that in my answer: your app becomes active, you get a notification.

Comment: That's true, forgot that. Thanks!